# Oracle SQL: clause Where : date_column=trunc(sysdate) result different to trunc(date_column)=trunc(sydate)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL developer to select data from a database. But I'm getting different results when i'm using the following in the WHERE Clause:

- `date_column=trunc(sysdate)` result different to
- `trunc(date_column)=trunc(sydate)`.

Also, the `date_column = sysdate` is returning no row even if I have corresponding data in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup.  In Oracle, the `date` data type is a bit misleading, because it has a time component.  So:

```
date_column = trunc(sysdate)
```

returns rows where `date_column` is at exactly midnight just passed.

```
trunc(date_column) = trunc(sysdate)
```

returns anything that happens today.

```
date_column = sysdate
```

Only works if the time components match, which is highly unlikely.

I would often write the logic as:

```
date_column >= trunc(sysdate) and date_column < trunc(sysdate + 1)
```

This method ensures that an index on `date_column` can be used for the filtering.